# Convert structured content of text file to list with dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading a text file like this:

```
ATTACHMENT1=:1.xlsm
ATTACHMENT1RNG1=:Entity
ATTACHMENT1VRNG1=:TOT^^ENT1
ATTACHMENT1RNG2=:country
ATTACHMENT1VRNG2=:A
ATTACHMENT2=:2.xlsm
ATTACHMENT2RNG1=:Entity
ATTACHMENT2VRNG1=:TOT
ATTACHMENT2RNG2=:dept
ATTACHMENT2VRNG2=:F0008
```

and want to load it in list with dictionaries as in:

```
[
{'File': [1.xlsm'], 'Entity': ['TOT', 'ENT1'], 'country': ['A']},
{'File': [2.xlsm'], 'Entity': ['TOT'], 'dept': ['F0008']}
]
```

'File' is a fixed prefix for ATTACHMENT1 and ATTACHMENT2.
For the other lines I would like to have the value of RNGx as dictionary keys and the values of VRNGx as dictionary values.

I know I can split lines on '=:', I can also split a string based on a separator, but I cannot figure out how to create this data structure myself.
Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could split on `=:` like you said, and if the first section has `VRNG` in it, you could take its second part as the key and split the following line on `^^` for the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can rely on the ordering, this is pretty easy to do with a state machine that just looks at the presence of the different suffixes:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = []
    key = ""
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.strip().split("=:")
        if "RNG" not in k:
            data.append({'File': [v]})
        elif "VRNG" not in k:
            key = v
        else:
            data[-1][key] = v.split("^^")

print(data)
```

```
[{'File': ['1.xlsm'], 'Entity': ['TOT', 'ENT1'], 'country': ['A']}, {'File': ['2.xlsm'], 'Entity': ['TOT'], 'dept': ['F0008']}]
```

Comment: Not so easy for me, still need to grow... 
Thank you very much for posting the snippet and your explanation! This is exactly what I need.